# SQL Server or Python adding a column to keep new insert as 0 meanwhile make existing table auto increment

Tags: python, sql-server

I've been searching many similar posts here but they seem not to meet my requirement to use SQL Server `IDENTITY`.

I have a dataframe extracted from another data source which might include duplicate Name.

**Dataframe**

| Date | Time | Name | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:00:00 | abc | 0.23 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:00:00 | abc | 0.19 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:05:00 | def | 0.36 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:10:00 | ghi | 0.29 |

When I load to SQL Server, I need to create a Retest_Count column in order to indicate the test order. If the Name is duplicated and same timestamp, always set the newer one to be 0 and the older one to be 1 based on the 'original data order'. Like this:

**SQL Table 1**

| Date | Time | Name | Result | Retest_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:00:00 | abc | 0.23 | 1 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:00:00 | abc | 0.19 | 0 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:05:00 | def | 0.36 | 0 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:10:00 | ghi | 0.29 | 0 |

When I insert new data with same Name but different timestamp, always give 0 to the new data and the existing table need to get auto increment like this:

**SQL Table 2**

| Date | Time | Name | Result | Retest_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:00:00 | abc | 0.23 | 2 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:00:00 | abc | 0.19 | 1 |
| 3/29/2022 | 13:00:00 | abc | 0.18 | 0 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:05:00 | def | 0.36 | 0 |
| 3/28/2022 | 7:10:00 | ghi | 0.29 | 1 |
| 3/29/2022 | 21:05:00 | ghi | 0.25 | 0 |

Is this possible to achieve by SQL Server script? Python solution is considered also.

Comment: This would seem better as a column in a `VIEW`, rather than a persisted value. You would still need an `IDENTITY` on your table, however, to denote the order of the data (as i assume it's coincidence that `Result` is in ascending order).

Comment: The purpose for this additional column is when I set Retest_Count = '0', I can always refer to the most updated data and filter out the old one.

Comment: You don't need a column like `Retest_Count` to achieve that, you could just use a [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) (which, again, you could use a `VIEW` for easy use). This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thank you! "Get top 1 row of each group" seems like a solution but if a duplicate data with same timestamp in the table, perhaps it couldn't identify. I'll still try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is far better suited for a `VIEW`. You will need to ensure you have some kind of column in your table that always increases (such as an `IDENTITY`) to achieve this though (as I note you have 2 tests that occur at the same time for the same Name, so there isn't a way to denote which is "first").

Then you can create a `VIEW` like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView_RetestCounts AS
    SELECT [Date],
           [Time],
           [Name],
           Result,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY IdentityColumn DESC) - 1 AS Retest_Count
    FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

If, however, your goal is to filter to the latest row, as your comments suggest, then use a `VIEW` with a [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) solution:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView_LatestTest AS
    WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT [Date],
               [Time],
               [Name],
               Result,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY IdentityColumn DESC) AS Retest_Count
        FROM dbo.YourTable)
    SELECT [Date],
           [Time],
           [Name],
           Result
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Retest_Count = 1;
```

Comment: When I used `ORDER BY [Date], [Time] DESC`, neither one gives me the reverse order. The latest record always has larger Retest_Count. Do you know why?

Comment: Because you're ordering by date **ascending** @KelvinLo .